# is Co-NP in PSPACE?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, space-complexity

Is Co-NP in PSPACE? I think it should obviously be, but I just wanted to make sure. I can find that NP is in PSPACE in Internet, but not on Co-NP.

Answer (score 10):

By the same reasoning that **NP** is in **PSPACE**, **co-NP** is in **co-PSPACE**. But **co-PSPACE** = **PSPACE** (you can just flip the answer), so **co-NP** is in **PSPACE**, too.